# Is there a canon explanation of WHY Data chose to enter Starfleet Academy?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

We know that Data went through Starfleet Academy and served in Starfleet.

But is there any canon info indicating **why** he choise that path/career/existence?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is. Data was "rescued" by Starfleet officers, which triggered him to follow that path, too.

From [Memory Alpha on Data](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Data#Discovery_and_early_career):

> Data was found and reactivated on the planet Omicron Theta by the USS Tripoli on February 2, 2338, after the Crystalline Entity destroyed the entire colony on the planet. (TNG: "Datalore") His connection with Starfleet resulted in his choice to enter Starfleet Academy. (TNG: "Brothers")

This is revealed in the episode [Brothers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Brothers_%28episode%29):

> On Terlina III, Soong expresses disappointment in his son's choice in having entered Starfleet Academy, and inquires as to his reason, to which Data replies that he wanted to repay the people who first discovered him with dedication to service.

More [visual evidence from the episode (around time 4:20)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_FnJTKSj34).